# Efficient way of expanding large products

Tags: performance-tuning, special-functions

I am working on some problem in physics/math in which I need a series expansion of a certain function, that is defined as an infinite product. I truncate this product to program it. The relevant part of my code is given by

```
\[Eta][q_] := q^(1/24)*QPochhammer[q, q]; 
\[Theta]1[q_, y_] := EllipticTheta[1, (1/(2*I))*Log[y], q^(1/2)]; 
\[Theta]2[q_, y_] := EllipticTheta[2, (1/(2*I))*Log[y], q^(1/2)]; 
\[Theta]3[q_, y_] := EllipticTheta[3, (1/(2*I))*Log[y], q^(1/2)]; 
\[Theta]4[q_, y_] := EllipticTheta[4, (1/(2*I))*Log[y], q^(1/2)]; 

\[Phi][q_, y_] := 8*((\[Theta]2[q, y]/\[Theta]2[q, 1])^2 + (\[Theta]3[q, y]/\[Theta]3[q, 1])^2 + (\[Theta]4[q, y]/\[Theta]4[q, 1])^2)

P\[Phi] = Normal[(Series[#1, {q, 0, 50}, {y, 0, 50}] & )[Assuming[y > 0 && u > 0, 
      Simplify[TrigToExp[Series[\[Phi][q, y], {q, 0, 50}]]]]]]; 

o = Exponent[P\[Phi], y, Min]

cc = CoefficientList[P\[Phi]/y^o, {q, y}]; 

\[CapitalPhi][p_, q_, y_] := p*q*y*Product[(1 - p^m*q^n*y^l)^cc[[m*n + 1,l - o + 1]], {m, 1, 6}, {n, 1, 6}, 
     {l, o, -o}]*Product[(1 - p^m*q^n*y^l)^cc[[m*n + 1,l - o + 1]], {m, 0, 0}, {n, 1, 6}, {l, o, -o}]*
    Product[(1 - p^m*q^n*y^l)^cc[[m*n + 1,l - o + 1]], {m, 1, 6}, {n, 0, 0}, {l, o, -o}]*
    Product[(1 - p^m*q^n*y^l)^cc[[m*n + 1,l - o + 1]], {m, 0, 0}, {n, 0, 0}, {l, o, -1}]; 

Normal[(Series[#1, {p, 0, 6}, {q, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 20}] & )[Assuming[y > 0 && u > 0, 
    Simplify[TrigToExp[Series[\[CapitalPhi][p, q, y], {p, 0, 6}, {q, 0, 6}]]]]]]
```

Note that `P\[Phi]` contains negative powers of $y$. That's why, when evaluating the coefficients of this Laurent series, I multiply by the $y^{-o}$, to shift the powers of $y$ to be all positive. Only then can the `CoefficientList` be used.

`\[CapitalPhi]` is the function I am interested in expanding. The rest of the code I hope speaks for itself
 The twice appearance of series is to have mathematica expand in such a way that it organizes the expression nicely, e.g. $p(q(y^2+y+...) + q^2 (\text{pol}(y))+ ...)) + p^2(...)$

I am interested in speeding up the code, as at the moment taking getting to order 7 in $p$ and $q$ is taking an hour or so. Any help would be much appreciated.

Note that the provided piece of code runs up to order 6 in $p$ and $q$.To expand to higher order, not only should I change the order of Series in the last line, but also the range of $m,n$ in the definition of `\[CapitalPhi]`.

Comment: Do you need it to 7th order in all variables?  Or would retaining `p^7` and `q^7` but losing `p^4 q^4` do?  The expansion is obviously much smaller in the latter case.

Comment: The image of your code is very low resolution and difficult to read.  Could you edit your answer by formatting your code in code blocks?  See [this guide](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1585/11035) for more advice.

Comment: @mikado yes I kind of do. My question is more if there is some quicker way of implementing these products over large amount of factors

Comment: @jjc385 hope it is a bit better like this

Comment: You need to provide code that works. For instance: 1. Provide a sample `cc` variable. 2. Typo: `{l, -6, , 6}` in the first product should be `{l, -6, 6}`. 3. `Phi[p, q, y]` is identically `0` because of the `m=0, n=0, l=0` term in the last product. Please fix these to provide working code. You should be able to quit the kernel, run your provided code, and have sensible output.

Comment: Are you sure the infinite product cannot be solved analytically?  (We cannot tell because you don't define `cc[[]]` and other functions.)

Comment: @CarlWoll: I provided now enough of the code and defintions to run it in mathematica. Taking large ranges for m,n in the products becomes very time consuming, on my computer from range up to 7 onwards (in the provided code the range is 6). the question then is: can this be computed more efficiently?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I think as of yet, this function (Igusa cusp form) is only known as an infinite product (or as so-called additive lift, but that still is an implicit deifntion using instead infinite sums)

Comment: I think you can insert the [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) inside of the [`Product`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Product): ``\[CaptialPhi][p_, q_, y_] := p q y Product[Series[.., {p, 0, 6}, {q, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 20}], {m, 6}, {n, 6}, {l, o, -o}] ..``

Comment: @CarlWoll That speeds it up indeed, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a product of [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) expressions will be much faster than finding the [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) of the product. So, the following is much faster:

```
term[m_,n_,l_] := Series[
    (1-p^m q^n y^l)^cc[[m n+1, l-o+1]],
    {p, 0, 6}, {q, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 20}
]

Φ[p_,q_,y_] := Times[
    p, q, y,
    Product[term[m,n,l], {m,1,6},{n,1,6},{l,o,-o}],
    Product[term[m,n,l], {m,0,0},{n,1,6},{l,o,-o}],
    Product[term[m,n,l], {m,1,6},{n,0,0},{l,o,-o}],
    Product[term[m,n,l], {m,0,0},{n,0,0},{l,o,-1}]
]

res = Φ[p, q, y]; //Timing
res //Short //TeXForm
```

{0.267555, Null}

> $\left(\left(\frac{1}{y}-2+y+O\left(y^{22}\right)\right)
>    q+\left(-\frac{2}{y^2}-\frac{16}{y}+36-16 y-2 y^2+O\left(y^{20}\right)\right)
>    q^2+\langle\langle 5\rangle\rangle +O\left(q^8\right)\right) p+\langle\langle
>    6\rangle\rangle +O\left(p^8\right)$

Comment: Thanks again, it was quite helpful. I guess it makes sense that series first and then product is quicker, since the number of terms grows exponentially with cc in the product, so first expanding it greatly reduces the number of terms taken in consideration, I guess.